# Problem with holding down the mouse buttons (SVEN RX-G740)

Tags: hardware, mouse

I recently bought a new SVEN RX-G740 mouse and during the game I noticed a small problem. If I hold down a click on the right and left mouse buttons at the same time and release one of them, then all the mouse buttons are released. In shooters where I need to aim down sights and shoot this is very inconvenient and I would like to know how to fix it.

In the [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvbRK.jpg), I'm trying to undo the pinched clicks one at a time, but when one button is canceled, all the other buttons are immediately released, even when I keep my finger on the button pressed. This happens with all buttons on the mouse.

Is it possible to fix this somehow or is this the model?

Comment: Is there any kind of software that controls the mouse? For example, Logitech has special software for their peripherals that you can tune them with.   Have you also tried reinstalling the driver?

Comment: I tried searching the mouse driver for my model, but didn't find any. Yes, I tried reinstalling the driver, but it didn't help. If you know any software that can help me with inconvenience, I'll be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update. After some more tests, I discovered that it's just the rmb and not all of them. I guess the right button is just loose or something. In that case I think I should just get my mouse back to the shop where I got it for guarantee.

I guess the moral of the story is to test the device problems more accurately so you could understand it and make decision.